# If $\sin x+\cos x=1+\sin x\cos x,$ then which of the following is/are correct?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question**

> If $\sin x+\cos x=1+\sin x\cos x,$ then which of the following is/are correct?
>
> > A) $\sin(x+\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$
> >
> > B) $\sin(x-\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$
> >
> > C) $\cos(x+\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$
> >
> > D) $\cos(x-\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$

**My Attempt:**

Squaring both sides, $$1+2\sin x\cos x=1+\sin^2x\cos^2x+2\sin x\cos x\\\implies\sin x\cos x=0\\\implies\sin2x=0\implies x=n\frac\pi2,n\in I$$

Thus, I am not able to match with any of the options.

Answer given is A, D.

Comment: You might eliminate the extraneous solutions by noting that your $n\in\{\ldots,-4,-3,0,1,4,5,8,9,\ldots\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the equation without doing anything complicated gives us:

$\sin (x)$ $[$ $1-\cos (x)$ $]$  $=$ $[$ $1-\cos (x)$ $]$

This is only true when one of the following statements hold:

- $\sin (x)= 1$ and $\cos (x)$ is unrestricted
- $\cos (x) =1$ and $\sin (x)$ is unrestricted

Now we can find values of $x$ that allow the original equation to hold. And from here, we can substitute in these values in order to test the statements that you have provided.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite as $\sin x \cdot (1-\cos x)-(1-\cos x)=0 \implies (\sin x-1)(1-\cos x)=0 \implies $ 
$ \sin x=1 \lor \cos x=1$ which matches options A), D)

Comment: Thanks a lot...